# Can you capture events from the 5 way directional buttons in Opera Mini using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mobile-website, opera-mini, keypad

Can you capture events from the 5-way keypad of a device using Opera Mini using Javascript?
(My guess is the answer is no, but I figured I'd ask anyway)

Comment: Kinda makes me wish they'd include this in the HTML5 spec though.  Oh well maybe HTML6 in 20 years or so will have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say **no**, because Opera says on their dev site that they don't support client side javascript after the page is loaded:

> There are a few more caveats specific
>   to Opera Mini 5 that developers need
>   to be aware of:  The majority of
>   JavaScript that is triggered onload
>   should work just fine, except in cases
>   where those scripts require
>   asynchronous operations. **JavaScript
>   won't run client-side (for instance in
>   response to user interaction) once the
>   page has finished loading.** Plug-ins,
>   such as Adobe Flash, are not
>   supported.

Source: [Opera Mini 5 specs](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-5-developers/)

Still, [Opera Mini does support other Javascript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-support-in-opera-mini-4/) actions, but they all get executed on the server.